# Is there an easy way to check what speed your USB device is connected in Windows 11

Tags: windows, usb, usb-storage

Sometimes I plug my USB HD and when I copy something it goes slower than other times. If I reconnect it may solve the problem. What I want is an easy way to check what speed the device is connected, before starting to copy things.